# this line is overwriting the array

Tags: php, loops, multidimensional-array

ok so i am creating a multidementional array and this line only allows one element into it. How do i check to see if

```
$related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']]
```

is greater then 0 and if so dont overwrite the value and just append onto it

```
while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']] = $row_r; //this line
```

Comment: Please give us more info on what you're trying to do. You specify that you want different behavior based on whether something is greater than 0, but it seems that it (at least sometimes) contains an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for this?

```
while($row_r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']][] = $row_r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$value=$related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']];
if(is_int($value) && $value>0) {//if current value is a >0 integer
  $related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']] = array($value, $new_value);//we combine the new value too, together with the previous one, into an array
} elseif(is_array($value)) {//if  it was already an array, we append the new element
  $related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']][] = $new_value;
} else {//other wise (a 0 integer), we would assign the value.
  $related[$row_r['Category_name']][$row_r['name']] = $new_value;
}
```